# JQuery Fullcalendar to filter event based on select dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

So, currently i am creating a fullcalendar on PHP which shows event based on dates from my database , my database is Microsoft Access using ODBC , before adding the eventRender function, my fullcalendar is working fine with a modal pop up function.

However after i added these few lines of code where i got it from an example from stackoverflow , my fullcalendar is not showing. I wonder if the code is compatible with what i wrote before.

**Here is my code for calendar**

```
<script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
         
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      {  
        title: '<?php echo $id?>',
        start: '<?php echo $newEnd?>', 
        end: '<?php echo $newEnd?>', 
        calibrator: '<?php echo $calibrator?>',
        description : '<?php echo $description?>',
        extendedProps : {
          ownerid : '<?php echo $ownerID?>',
          ownername : '<?php echo $ownerName?>',
          department : '<?php echo $depart?>',
          prevdate : '<?php echo $prevDate?>',
          duedate : '<?php echo $dueDate?>'
        },
        color : '<?php echo $color?>'
      }, 
      <?php } ?>
      ],

      eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
        return ['both', event.calibrator].indexOf($('#calibrator').val()) >= 0
      }

      $('#calibrator').on('change',function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
      });

      eventClick: function(event) {
      $("#successModal").modal("show");
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para").text(event.title);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para1").text(event.extendedProps.ownerid);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para2").text(event.extendedProps.ownername);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para3").text(event.extendedProps.department);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para4").text(event.description);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para5").text(event.extendedProps.prevdate);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para6").text(event.extendedProps.duedate);
      }

    });
  });
      </script>
```

**The event render part code**

```
 eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
        return ['both', event.calibrator].indexOf($('#calibrator').val()) >= 0
      }

      $('#calibrator').on('change',function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
      });
```

**After some advice , my events are showing for external and internal option , but not when i select the both selection**

```
<script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
         
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                      
      header: {
      left:   'prevYear,nextYear',
      center: 'title',
      right:  'prev,next today'
      },
        defaultView: 'month',
        showNonCurrentDates:false,
        fixedWeekCount:false,
        contentHeight:"auto",
        handleWindowResize:true,

      events: [
        <?php 
            include 'connect.php';

      function getColor($date) {
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $oneweekDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 week'));
        $eventColor = '';

        if($date < $currentDate){
            $eventColor = '#FF0000';
        } else if($date >= $currentDate && $date < $oneweekDate){
            $eventColor = '#FFA500';
        } else{
            $eventColor = '#008000';
        }
        return $eventColor;
    }

            $sql="SELECT * FROM masterlist1 WHERE Tool_Status = 'Active'";
            $result=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
            while($row=odbc_fetch_array($result)){
        $newEnd = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['Calibration_Due_Date']));
        $color = getColor($newEnd);
        $id = $row['Form_Tracking_ID'];
        $ownerID = $row['Owner_I_Employee_ID'];
        $ownerName = $row['Owner_I_Name'];
        $calibrator = $row['Calibrator'];
                $description = $row['Description1'];
        $prevDate = date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['Date2']));
        $dueDate = date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['Calibration_Due_Date']));
        $depart = $row['Department1'];
        ?>
      {  
        title: '<?php echo $id?>',
        start: '<?php echo $newEnd?>', 
        end: '<?php echo $newEnd?>', 
        calibrator: '<?php echo $calibrator?>',
        description : '<?php echo $description?>',
        extendedProps : {
          ownerid : '<?php echo $ownerID?>',
          ownername : '<?php echo $ownerName?>',
          department : '<?php echo $depart?>',
          prevdate : '<?php echo $prevDate?>',
          duedate : '<?php echo $dueDate?>'
        },
        color : '<?php echo $color?>'
      }, 
      <?php } ?>
      ],

      eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
        return ['both', event.calibrator].indexOf($('#calibrator').val()) >= 0
      },

      eventClick: function(event) {
      $("#successModal").modal("show");
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para").text(event.title);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para1").text(event.extendedProps.ownerid);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para2").text(event.extendedProps.ownername);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para3").text(event.extendedProps.department);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para4").text(event.description);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para5").text(event.extendedProps.prevdate);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para6").text(event.extendedProps.duedate);
      }

    });

    $('#calibrator').on('change',function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
      });
  });
      </script>
```

**This is my selector code**

```
 <select name="calibrator" id="calibrator">
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
    <option value="External">External</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Check your browser console are you seeing any error there ?

Comment: It says syntax error and i noticed that my eventRender is in yellow color while my eventClick is in light blue color . Im using VSCode.

Comment: Move that whole event handler outside your initializing code.

Comment: Sorry but which part ? the event render part ?

Comment: This event handling code: `$('#calibrator').on('change',function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
      });` belongs outside your calendar options

Comment: You mean i should put it outside my fullcalendar code ?

Comment: Also `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ events: [
      {  
        title: '<?php echo $id?>',
        start: '<?php echo $newEnd?...` looks like a typo, should be `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      {  
        title: '<?php echo $id?>',
        start: '<?php echo $newEnd?...`

Comment: `You mean i should put it outside my fullcalendar code `....yes. right now you're trying to put it randomly In the middle of an object (your options list), that simply isn't valid in JavaScript (and also doesn't make sense logically)

Comment: For the typo u mean i need to remove the event wording sir ?

Comment: Also `eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
        return ['both', event.calibrator].indexOf($('#calibrator').val()) >= 0
      }` needs a `,` at the end, so that the list format is maintained and the next option after it (the eventClick) can also be read - i.e. `eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
        return ['both', event.calibrator].indexOf($('#calibrator').val()) >= 0
      },`

Comment: `For the typo u mean i need to remove the event wording sir`...no I didn't suggest removing anything...I meant it looked like you missed out some code. Maybe you just made a mistake pasting it into your question?

Comment: To understand why that might be, we'd need to see the actual event data being generated by your PHP. You can see it if you load your event page and then use the View Source feature in your browser - it'll show the generated data rather than the raw PHP

Comment: The events are showing now , but only for internal and external options, not for both, i was wondering how can i change the event render part to be able to show both external and internal data if i selected the both option?

Comment: It's hard for us to understand without seeing some examples of the event data, and what options are available in your drop-down box. Please update the question

Comment: Ah so it just came out that the it should be Both instead of both in the eventrender part. Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Adyson, i was able to pinpoint my mistakes and made the code work.

The problem before this was i should put rerenderevents part out side of the fullcalendar JS code , and i forgot to but a ',' after calling eventRender function.

**Below is my code for selector part**

```
<select name="calibrator" id="calibrator">
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
    <option value="External">External</option>
</select>
```

**Code for my fullcalendar**

```
<script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
         
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                      
      header: {
      left:   'prevYear,nextYear',
      center: 'title',
      right:  'prev,next today'
      },
        defaultView: 'month',
        showNonCurrentDates:false,
        fixedWeekCount:false,
        contentHeight:"auto",
        handleWindowResize:true,

      events: [
        <?php 
            include 'connect.php';

      function getColor($date) {
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $oneweekDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 week'));
        $eventColor = '';

        if($date < $currentDate){
            $eventColor = '#FF0000';
        } else if($date >= $currentDate && $date < $oneweekDate){
            $eventColor = '#FFA500';
        } else{
            $eventColor = '#008000';
        }
        return $eventColor;
    }

            $sql="SELECT * FROM masterlist1 WHERE Tool_Status = 'Active'";
            $result=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
            while($row=odbc_fetch_array($result)){
        $newEnd = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['Calibration_Due_Date']));
        $color = getColor($newEnd);
        $id = $row['Form_Tracking_ID'];
        $ownerID = $row['Owner_I_Employee_ID'];
        $ownerName = $row['Owner_I_Name'];
        $calibrator = $row['Calibrator'];
                $description = $row['Description1'];
        $prevDate = date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['Date2']));
        $dueDate = date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['Calibration_Due_Date']));
        $depart = $row['Department1'];
        ?>
      {  
        title: '<?php echo $id?>',
        start: '<?php echo $newEnd?>', 
        end: '<?php echo $newEnd?>', 
        calibrator: '<?php echo $calibrator?>',
        description : '<?php echo $description?>',
        extendedProps : {
          ownerid : '<?php echo $ownerID?>',
          ownername : '<?php echo $ownerName?>',
          department : '<?php echo $depart?>',
          prevdate : '<?php echo $prevDate?>',
          duedate : '<?php echo $dueDate?>'
        },
        color : '<?php echo $color?>'
      }, 
      <?php } ?>
      ],

      eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
        return ['Both', event.calibrator].indexOf($('#calibrator').val()) >= 0
      },

      eventClick: function(event) {
      $("#successModal").modal("show");
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para").text(event.title);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para1").text(event.extendedProps.ownerid);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para2").text(event.extendedProps.ownername);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para3").text(event.extendedProps.department);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para4").text(event.description);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para5").text(event.extendedProps.prevdate);
      $("#successModal .modal-body #para6").text(event.extendedProps.duedate);
      }

    });

    $('#calibrator').on('change',function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
      });
  });
</script>
```

For my fullcalendar code , it comes with a modal popup that shows the details of the events using the data fetched from database.